# Get jar version when manifest file not contains it

Tags: java

I want to know how to get the jar version when the manifest file does not include it?

Comment: When you unpack the .jar and look in the manifest, it doesn't have the version?

Comment: yer it does not contains it. thats the issue

Comment: Do you have the source files? You could just recompile it.

Comment: If the JAR was built by Maven you might be able to get something useful out of the META-INF/maven entries but there's no general approach (or even any general definition of what the concept of "version of the JAR" really _means_) if the manifest doesn't give you anything useful.

Comment: If the manifest does not contain the version, then the jar is not versioned.  In this case, the jar version is "not versioned".

Answer (score 2):

The JAR's manifest is where the version is supposed to be stored. According to [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/versioning/spec/versioning2.html#wp89936) from Oracle on product versioning, the following attribute names are defined for a package. The value of each attribute is a string:

- `Package-Title` Title of the package
- `Package-Version` Version number
- `Package-Vendor` Vendors company or organization
- `Specification-Title` Title of the specification
- `Specification-Version` Version number
- `Specification-Vendor` Vendors company or organization

If the manifest doesn't contain the package version, then package wasn't created with this information available. You cannot really just make it up or get elsewhere, at least not in any standard sense.